# Can I use ArrayList<String>, map or hashmap in loops as expressions or statements to have less repetition on my code?

Tags: android, kotlin, repeat

My menu items will be increased a lot so Id like to know can I use Array, map or hashmap in expressions to have less repetition. Now I have

```
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    // Handle item selection
    var messages: ArrayList<String>
    var timestamps: ArrayList<String>
    var linknames: ArrayList<String>
    var parsedData: ParsedData

    return when (item.itemId) {
        dataIdRead[0] -> {
            Thread(Runnable {
                parsedData = GetMessages(dataCity[0]).getParsedData()
                timestamps = parsedData.timestamps
                messages = parsedData.messages
                linknames = parsedData.linknames
                runOnUiThread {
                    rv_message_list.adapter =
                        MessageAdapter(messages, timestamps, linknames, this)
                    button.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                }
            }).start()
            true
        }

        dataIdRead[1] -> {
            Thread(Runnable {
                parsedData = GetMessages(dataCity[1]).getParsedData()
                timestamps = parsedData.timestamps
                messages = parsedData.messages
                linknames = parsedData.linknames
                runOnUiThread {
                    rv_message_list.adapter =
                        MessageAdapter(messages, timestamps, linknames, this)
                    button.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                }
            }).start()
            true
        }
        dataIdRead[2] -> {
            Thread(Runnable {
                parsedData = GetMessages(dataCity[2]).getParsedData()
                timestamps = parsedData.timestamps
                messages = parsedData.messages
                linknames = parsedData.linknames
                runOnUiThread {
                    rv_message_list.adapter =
                        MessageAdapter(messages, timestamps, linknames, this)
                    button.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                }
            }).start()
            true
        }
        else -> super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
```

and

```
   val dataIdRead = arrayOf(R.id.helsinki, R.id.vantaa, R.id.espoo)
   val dataCity = arrayOf("helsinki", "vantaa", "espoo")
```

Something that would make it to look something like this

```
return when (item.itemId) {
        *some magic* -> {
            Thread(Runnable {
                parsedData = GetMessages(*some magic*).getParsedData()
                timestamps = parsedData.timestamps
                messages = parsedData.messages
                linknames = parsedData.linknames
                runOnUiThread {
                    rv_message_list.adapter =
                        MessageAdapter(messages, timestamps, linknames, this)
                    button.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                }
            }).start()
            true
        }
        else -> super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
```

I have tried example forEach but at the beginning line `return when (item.itemId) {` waits expression and I didnt got far with that.

Comment: First answer solved this.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need a loop for this. Just get the index of dataIdRead. if it is not -1, then paste this index into dataCity.

```
val index =  dataIdRead.indexOf(item.itemId) 
return if(index == -1) { 
     print("item not found")
     super.onOptionsItemSelected(item) }
else {
      Thread(Runnable {
            parsedData = GetMessages(dataCity[ index ]).getParsedData()
            timestamps = parsedData.timestamps
            messages = parsedData.messages
            linknames = parsedData.linknames
            runOnUiThread {
                rv_message_list.adapter =
                    MessageAdapter(messages, timestamps, linknames, this)
                button.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            }
        }).start()
        true
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked and I was able to extend this to sub-menus too. Though I still need to think how this thing works.